# Heuristics of overdetermined systems made precise

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, microlocal-analysis

Given a map $\Phi$ that sends functions $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of $n$ variables to functions $\Phi f(y_1,\dots,y_m)$ of $m$ variables, there is the heuristic that solving the equation $\Phi f = g$ is only possible if the system is (over-)determined in the sense that $m\ge n$. I would like to know whether there is a setting in which this can be made precise.

Here is a first (failed) attempt: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact manifolds of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively and $\Phi$ is a map  $\Phi:C(X)\rightarrow C(Y)$ between their spaces of continuous functions. I interpret the heuristics to say that
$$
\Phi \text{ injective } \quad \Longrightarrow \quad m\ge n.
$$
Now arguably the nicest form $\Phi$ can take is $\Phi=\varphi^*$, the pull-back by a continuous  surjection $\varphi: Y\rightarrow X$. But alas, one can construct such a surjection from $S^1$ onto $S^2$ (starting with a space filling curve), and thus we do not necessarily have $m\ge n$.

Fair enough, continuous maps can be pretty wild. If we consider $\Phi:C^\infty(X)\rightarrow C^\infty(Y)$, then the counterexample from above does not carry over. Indeed, Sard's theorem implies that there can only be a smooth surjection $\varphi:Y\rightarrow X$ if $m\ge n$. This leads to:

**Question.** Let $X,Y$ be compact, smooth manifolds and $\Phi:C^\infty(X)\rightarrow C^\infty(Y)$ a continuous map. Which conditions on $\Phi$ ensure that $\Phi$ being injective implies that $\dim Y \ge \dim X$? For the start, it would be good to know whether it suffices to have $\Phi$ linear or whether additional structure on the Schwartz kernel is needed.

Comment: What topology are you putting on $C^\infty X$?

Comment: The standard Fréchet topology, i.e. $f_n\rightarrow 0$ iff $\Vert Pf_n \Vert_{L^\infty}\rightarrow 0$ for all differential operators $P$.

Comment: It seems like it would be difficult to come up with conditions in terms of abstract vector spaces. iirc $C^\infty X$ and $C^\infty Y$ are isomorphic as Fréchet spaces, provided both $X$ and $Y$ are compact and have nonzero dimension.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that, but that is good to know. From an abstract point of view (and with an eye on Gelfand's theory) one can maybe say something if $\Phi$ is an algebra homomorphism? Otherwise one  potentially does need a better understanding of the Schwartz kernel. (I would like to suggest something like '$\Phi$ being an elliptic FIO', but I am not very familiar with this and hoped one could give answer without...)